# Running pyinstaller on Windows 11

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I created a small app that I wanted to share with my gf, so I installed pyinstaller on my Mac and it created .exec file, but my gf uses Windows.
So I switched to my Windows computer, installed python, pip and pyinstaller there, but I had problems with that.
Namely, on Windows 11 Python modules don't respond to `python` or `python3` commands. You have to type `py` or `py -3 -m` to install, for example, pip.

So I tried almost everything with that pyinstaller I finally got, but the closest I was to run it, was that I got the error `no module named pyinstaller`, but when I typed `py -3 -m pip freeze`, I got the notion that I already have a pyinstaller module on my machine.

Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Namely, on Windows 11 Python modules don't respond to python or python3 commands."  Either I have misunderstood you or you do not have python installed correctly because if I pull up command prompt and type "python" it works fine.

Comment: When I open PowerShell, I get the notion that I am in my user directory on C. I typed in Python but this time it opened Windows Store. I removed the Python I installed from the official source and installed the version from the store. It seems to be working better now. Thanks :)

Comment: Is your Python installation dir listed in the PATH environment variable?

Comment: Yes it is, @Raphael, if you are trying to find an answer I wouldn't have time to check it right now

Comment: @Swantewit I was just speculating, that maybe you recently upgraded to Win 11 and that may have deleted the entries. But that's not the case.

Comment: Nope, it isn't @Raphael

Answer (score 3):

The same happened to me. I just needed to type the following in the console

```
py -m PyInstaller filename.py
```

The thing is that on my machine, pyinstaller module has the name PyInstaller, and the same could be happening to you.

Comment: Thanks. My GF has a Python that makes exe files from scripts, so I could check that solution in future if I bump on the same problem again :)

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall the current version of python and make sure to add python to pip :

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

After it is installed go to your folder where your file has been saved and on the [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIwRv.png)

After going to the path of the selected folder type cmd

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w 'filename.py'
```

after that the terminall will execute certain commands and hopefully, your file will be created to an exe
if it still doesn't work Try adding pip to your environment variables!

Comment: Ok I think this brought me a step closer.
I have reinstalled the Python with the version from the Windows Store and now "python" commands started working.
I have also added a pyinstaller location as a variable, but still I get the info that the pyinstaller can't find the file even though I copy and paste its name.